# Should I use Parallel.ForEach or regular foreach to process IO data from network

Tags: c#, io

I want to make API calls as fast as possible, my current code is:

```
List<MyItems> items;
foreach(items as item){
await item.GetData();
}
```

Should I consider using Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: If you're getting data from a network connection you will probably *hinder* performance by running it in parallel. Don't ask, *try it*. Or read this blog post: "[*Which is faster*](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)" by Eric Lippert.

Comment: If your `GetData()` is already async, then I would use `await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(i => i.GetData()));`

Comment: Glorin's comment is the answer - exactly as Cleary suggests in his book. Glorin - post it as an answer so we can upvote it!

Comment: well, TPL has an advantage over regular TAP: it can use hardware cores to parallelize work